# How to debug Protractor test (using Angular CLI ng e2e) with IntelliJ?

Tags: angular, debugging, intellij-idea, protractor, angular-cli

In my Angular 6 app created with Angular CLI, I'm running my Protractor e2e tests using via:

`ng e2e`

I was wondering how it is possible to set breakpoints and debug it in IntelliJ.

Comment: Have you tried Protractor Run/Debug configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-protractor.html ?

Comment: @y.bedrov How does it work without IntelliJ?

Comment: Sorry, do you need debug without IDE?

Comment: OP, did you find a way to do this?